# How to fix Libreoffice and Python3-uno

Tags: apt, python, libreoffice, dependencies

I cannot install any new packages because of python3-uno dependency problems. Apt-get said that python3-uno depends on libreoffice-core (=1:3.5.7-0ubuntu4) but 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu5 is to be installed. I tried purging libreoffice * with no luck. Now I can open the Libre Office core but cannot make any files because they are all grayed out. How do I fix Libre Office and resolve the python3-uno dependency problems?

EDIT:I forgot to mention I'm running 12.04. Purging python3-uno and libreoffice* did not help. Installing updates on update manager and disabled all of my third party sources (except for the one called third party sources or something like that). Apt-get update did not help either. I'm afraid to upgrade the distribution because last time I tried to I got the black screen when starting up after install error. 
[image: Libre Office core]

Comment: Try downloading, and installing from [Here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/python3-uno).  Make sure you choose your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Note the red sign on your top right. There is something fishy with your repositories. You should try 'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade'. If it doesn't work you probably have some rogue PPA in your sources, try disabling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the following command,

```
 sudo apt-get purge python3-uno
```

it told me something about /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-uno.prerm and py3clean. I removed python3-uno.prerm and reinstalled libreoffoffice and it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-uno libreoffice*
```

And then reinstall, but you'll have to reinstall any package that depends on python3-uno

Comment: I got the exact same problem on Ubuntu 21.04 with libreoffice and python3-uno.
This command line solve it. Thanks.